# Loop over variable and concatenate with string

Tags: variables, ansible, yaml, jinja2

Suppose I have an array in ansible:

```
vars:
  loopme: ['somesing', 'someothersing']
  concatenateme: 'constant'
```

How do i iterate over the list and concat value from list with the variable concatenateme?

So I get `somesingconstant` and `someothersingconstant` and put the result into a field in the task? Perhaps with jinja?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to apply `regex_replace` filter to every element of your list and replace "end of string" (`$`) with your constant:

---

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    loopme: ['somesing', 'someothersing']
    concatenateme: 'constant'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ loopme | map('regex_replace','$',concatenateme) | list }}"
```

Comment: will this be an array?

Comment: yes, it will be a list: `[ "somesingconstant", "someothersingconstant" ]`

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying this out:
unhashable type: 'list'
This is the value I'm trying to assign:
backup_directories: "{{ backup_directories | map('regex_replace','^',backup_snapshot_prefix) | list }}"
Any ideas?

Comment: In the general case you would have to escape any backslashes in the `concatenateme` value because otherwise `regex_replace` will try to swallow those.