# Create a cert with multiple subject alt names with Ansible

Tags: ssl, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using a block like below

```
- name: Ensure that the existing certificate has a certain domain in its subjectAltName
  openssl_certificate:
    path: /etc/ssl/crt/example.com.crt
    provider: selfsigned
    subject_alt_name:
      - www.example.com
      - test.example.com
```

To generate a selfsigned cert with Ansible, I'd like to use the ips in my inventory file as subject_alt_names something like

```
- name: Generate cert
  openssl_certificate:
    path: ssl/mongo-test.crt
    privatekey_path: ssl/mongo-test.pem
    csr_path: ssl/mongo-test.csr
    provider: selfsigned
    subject_alt_name: 
      - IP:{{hostvars[item].ansible_host}}
```

So that I end up with

```
- name: Generate cert
  openssl_certificate:
    path: ssl/mongo-test.crt
    privatekey_path: ssl/mongo-test.pem
    csr_path: ssl/mongo-test.csr
    provider: selfsigned
    subject_alt_name: 
      - IP:10.136.31.37
      - IP:10.136.29.52
      - IP:10.136.30.53
```

How do I get all my inventory ips to come under the subject_alt_name list?

I've tried using with_items but that creates a new cert per ip address and each iteration overwrites the last.

Comment: Make list of IPs (see `extract` filter), prepend each element with `IP:` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331312/loop-over-variable-and-concatenate-with-string/45331490#45331490))

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I think I can solve this with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that I am not answering to your question directly but I had the same problem and I chose another approach, hopping it could apply to you too.

I created an `openssl.conf` file that is templated with `Jinja`:

```
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
{% if letsencrypt_sans_domains[item] is defined and letsencrypt_sans_domains[item] | length > 0 %}
req_extensions     = req_ext
{% endif %}

string_mask = utf8only
default_md = sha256

[ req_distinguished_name ]
O=Organization
L=Boston
ST=Massachusetts
C=US
CN={{ item }}

{% if letsencrypt_sans_domains[item] is defined and letsencrypt_sans_domains[item] | length > 0 %}
[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = {{ item }}
{% set i = 2 %}
{% for domain in letsencrypt_sans_domains[item] %}
DNS.{{ i }} = {{ domain }}
{% set i = i + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Then I deploy the file using `template` module and call:

```
- name: "Generate CSR"
  command: "openssl req -config openssl_req_{{ item }}.conf -nodes -new -newkey rsa:4096 -out {{ item }}.csr -keyout {{ item }}.key"
  with_items: "{{ letsencrypt_domains | default([]) }}"
```

The variables `letsencrypt_sans_domains` and `letsencrypt_domains` point to:

```
letsencrypt_domains: [
  "a.b.com"
],
letsencrypt_sans_domains: {
  "a.b.com": [ "b.b.com", "c.b.com", "d.b.com" ]
}
```

}

Of course if `letsencrypt` is your use case, you'll need to answer the challenge for all SANs domain

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, my usecase is generating certs for mongo but this could potentially solve this for me.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. You've got a lot of resources on how to do it using openssl if you want to know more because the template can be change to fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via

```
   - name: Generate an OpenSSL CSR with subjectAltName extension with dynamic list
      openssl_csr:
        path: /etc/ssl/csr/www.ansible.com.csr
        privatekey_path: /etc/ssl/private/ansible.com.pem
        subject_alt_name: "{{ item.value | map('regex_replace', '^', 'IP:') | list }}"
      with_dict:
        ips:
        - 10.10.0.11
        - 10.10.0.12
        - 10.10.0.13
```